# How to build a Model Layer in Vue3 just like other MVC language?

Tags: model-view-controller, axios, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

my name is DP, I have 2 years Vue2 experience, but I am new to Vue3. I am learning Vue3 recently, as I found the "setup(Composition API)" just like the "Controller(in MVC)" that I did in other language, so I am trying to build my test Vue3 project in MVC way, but I go some problem can anyone help? thx!

### MVC Plan

```
M - use class
V - use <template> ... </template>
C - use setup
```

### My Problem

working: using loadTopic_inSetup().then() in setup is working, because topicList_inSetup is defined in setup() too.

not working: using loadTopic_inModel() in setup is not working, I guess some kind data keep problem, because in console I can see the data already got from API

as u can see, I am not expert for js/ts, I am a backend developer, so if you know how to do it, plz help thx very much.

BTW, VUE is greet, I love it.

### My Code

```
//APIBased.ts

import { ajax } from "@/lib/eeAxios"

export class APIBased {
    //load data with given url and params
    loadData(apiPath: string, params?: object): Promise<any> {
        apiPath = '/v1/'+apiPath
        return ajax.get(apiPath, params)
    }
}
```

//Topic.ts
    
    import { APIBased } from "./APIBased";
    import { ref } from 'vue'

```
export class Topic extends APIBased {
    //try keep data in model
    topicList: any = ref([]);

    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    //direct return ajax.get, let setup do the then+catch
    loadTopic_inSetup() {
        return super.loadData('topics', { t_type_id: 1 })
    }    
    
    //run ajax get set return data to this.topicList, keep data in model
    loadTopic_inModel() {
        super.loadData('topics', { t_type_id: 1 }).then((re) => {
            console.log(re.data)
            this.topicList = re.data
        })
    }
}
```

```
//EETest.vue
<template>
  <EELayoutMainLayout>
    <template v-slot:mainContent>
      <h1>{{ "Hello Vue3 !!" }}</h1>

      <hr/>
      {{to.topicList}} //not working... just empty array
      
      <hr/>
      {{topicList_inSetup}} //working... topic list return from API show here.
      
    </template>
  </EELayoutMainLayout>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, getCurrentInstance, ref } from 'vue'
import EELayoutMainLayout from '@/components/eeLayout/EELayoutMainLayout.vue'

import { Topic } from "@/models/Topic";

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'EETest',
  props: {
  },
  setup() {
    let topicList_inSetup = ref([])
    
    const to = new Topic()
    
    //try keep data in setup, it's working
    to.loadTopic_inSetup().then((re) => {
      topicList_inSetup.value = re.data
      console.log(re.data)
    })
    
    //try keep data in model, the function is run, api return get, but data not show, even add ref in model
    to.loadTopic_inModel()

    return {
      topicList,
      to,
    }
  },
  components: {
    EELayoutMainLayout,
  },
})

</script>
```

Comment: One thing I see in your `Topic` class, `topicList` is a ref, so you need to assign the response data to its value.

Answer (score 0):

A few digressions before solving the problem. Maybe you are a java developer. I personally think it is inappropriate to write the front end with Java ideas. The design of vue3's setup is more inclined to combined functional programming

To fully understand why you need some pre knowledge, **Proxy** and **the get and set method of Object**
They correspond to the two core apis in vue, **reactive** and **ref**,
The former can only be applied to objects( because proxy can only proxy objects),The latter can be applied to any type(primary for basic javascript types, get and set can apply for any type)
You can modify the code to meet your expectations

```
loadTopic_inModel() {
   super.loadData('topics', { t_type_id: 1 }).then((re) => {
      console.log(re.data)
      this.topicList.value = re.data
   })
}
```

You cannot modify a ref object directly, a test case to explain what is reactive
when ref function is called, a will be like be wrapped in a class has value properties, and has get and set method

the effect function will call the arrow function, and in this time, the get method of a will be called and it will track as a dependence of the effect function, when a changed, the set method of a will be called, and it will trigger the arrow function,
so when you direct modify the a, the setter method will never trigger, the view will not update

```
const a = ref(1)
let dummy
let calls = 0
effect(() => {
  calls++
  dummy = a.value
})
expect(calls).toBe(1)
expect(dummy).toBe(1)
a.value = 2
expect(calls).toBe(2)
expect(dummy).toBe(2)
// same value should not trigger
a.value = 2
expect(calls).toBe(2)
```